# Array Errors Java

Tags: java, arrays

When I compile the java code, I met the problem:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 11

```
at watercount.trap(watercount.java:41)
at watercount.main(watercount.java:14)
```

It seems that the Array is not used correctly, but I can not figure out.  Thanks for your help !

```
import java.util.Arrays;


public class watercount {

    public static void main (String args[]){

    int[] Array = new int[] {1,3,4,6,8,12,2,3,4,5,10};


    int water_num;

    water_num = trap(Array);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Array));


    }



    public static int trap (int[] A) 

    { int trap=0;
      int high=0;

      if (A==null) return trap;

      int []leftHigh = new int[A.length];
      int []rightHigh = new int[A.length];

      for(int i=0; i<A.length; i++){
          if(A[i]>high) high = A[i];
          leftHigh[i]=high;  
      }

      high=0;

      for(int i=A.length;i>=0;i--){
          if(A[i]>high) high = A[i];
          rightHigh[i]=high;  
      }

      for(int i=0; i<A.length; i++)

      {trap+=Math.min(rightHigh[i],leftHigh[i])-A[i];}

     return trap;



    }
```

Comment: There are literally hundreds, if not thousands, of previously answered questions on Stack Overflow that would have provided you with a solution. Please do your due diligence by searching both Stack Overflow and Google *prior* to asking a question -- particularly with regard to an issue as common as this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second `for` loop that iterates `i` backwards starts at an invalid index -- `A.length`.  It's an "off by one" error.  Start at the maximum possible index `A.length - 1` instead:

```
for(int i=A.length - 1; i>=0; i--){
```